# “Da, wo ich herkomme, schon.”

Tags: translation, german-to-english, sentence-structure, redundancy

I’ve come across the expression

> Da, wo ich herkomme, schon.

From context, I gather that it means something like ‘That’s how it is where I come from’.

Is something being omitted/left unsaid in *Da, wo ich herkomme, schon*?  Or is it a grammatically complete sentence?

Comment: possible alternative translation: "Where I come from you do"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes, most of the main clause is omitted, presumably because it would have to repeat what has just been said by another speaker. A contrived example:

> – Man klettert nicht nachts um drei Uhr auf Apfelbäume.
>   – Da, wo ich herkomme, schon. (= Da, wo ich herkomme, macht man das schon. = Da, wo ich herkomme, klettert man schon nachts um drei Uhr auf Apfelbäume.)

Omitting redundant information in this way (called *ellipsis*) is done all the time:

> – Kannst du mit dem Hund Gassi gehen?
>   – Klar. (= Klar kann ich mit dem Hund Gassi gehen).

It isn’t specific to German, either:

> – Sarah, will you have this man to be your husband, to live together with him in the covenant of marriage? Will you love him, comfort him, honor and keep him, in sickness and in health; and, forsaking all others, be faithful unto him as long as you both shall live?
>   – Yes, I will. (= Yes, I will have this man to be my husband, to live together with him in the covenant of marriage, and I will love him … … ….)